# get the selected item added dynamically jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I managed to dynamically add input fields using this code :
My HTML :

```
<div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <div class="card mb-4 form_field_outer  ">
                                        <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row ">
                                         <form>
                                            <div class="form-row">
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                                                    <select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="id_casting">
                                                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                                        @foreach($castings as $casting)
                                                               <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                                                    <label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label>
                                                    <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="id_modele_contrat">
                                                        <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                                        <option>...</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="card-body ">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div> 
                                        </form>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>


                                </div>

                            </div>
```

My script :

$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $("body").on("click",".add_new_frm_field_btn", function (){ 

        console.log("clicked");

        var index = $(".form_field_outer").find(".form_field_outer_row").length + 1;
        $(".form_field_outer").append(
            `
            <div class="col-12">

            <div class="card-body form_field_outer_row">

            <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Casting</label>
                <select id="id_casting" class="form-control" name="id_casting">
                    <option selected>Choose...</option>
                    @foreach($castings as $casting)
                      <option data-id="{{$casting->id_casting}}" value="{{$casting->id_casting}}">{{$casting->nom.' '.$casting->prenom}}</option>
                      @endforeach
                 </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <label for="inputState">Type de contrat</label>
            <select id="id_modele_contrat" class="form-control" name="id_modele_contrat">
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            <option>...</option>
            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body ">

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning mb-1 remove_node_btn_frm_field">Delete</button>

            </div>

            </div>

            </div>

            </div>
            `);

        $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field:not(:first)").prop("disabled", false);
        $(".form_field_outer").find(".remove_node_btn_frm_field").first().prop("disabled", true);

    });


});
```

No, I'm trying to get the `id_casting` of each selected item in `selecbox` for each added rows

So I tried the following scipt :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
       
       $("#id_casting").change(function(){

        console.log("clickk");
        let id_casting = $(this).find("option:selected").data("id");
        console.log(id_casting);
           });
       });

/*  });*/

</script>
```

Bu this script get only the `id_casting` of the first row and when I add a new row and I select item from select-box it doesn't get the `id_casting` of the selected item of select-box added
dynamically.

Comment: You cannot use same id for mutliple elements . Also, your select-box are dynamically created so you need bind your event handler with static element . So , simply change handler like this `$(document).on("change","select[name=id_casting]",function(){ //all code here })`